# jQuery - Change the text of a id

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="responsive" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="processorTitle" class="modal-title">Responsive</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /modal -->
```

I want to change the text of "processorTitle" but it is not working.

jQuery:

```
$(".changeLanguage").click(function(){
  $("#processorTitle").html('awesome text');
  $("#responsive").modal("show");
  $.get(window.assetsFolder + "files/languages/" + $(this).attr("requestLanguage") + ".lang")
      .done(function(data) {

      })
      .fail(function() {

      });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A classic JavaScript line should just do the job:

document.getElementById('processorTitle').innerHTML=' new text ';

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are including the jQuery library which isn't included in your code snippet, but inferred based on your first attempt:

`$("#processorTitle").html("test");`

Comment: Can we see the entire source, please.

Comment: Thanks @FabianHell for the update. However, if you can include the full source still that would be great. Hard to tell without seeing the function that the contains the jQuery makes it difficult to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: have included the full jquery function. the modal is displayed but without affects on the text.

Comment: @FabianHell Is there another element with the same ID in the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('processorTitle').innerHTML='awesome text';
```

jquery:

```
$('#processorTitle').html('awesome text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Form elements have text properties, but other HTML elements (like the `H4` in your example) do not. Instead, they have `innerHTML`.

In plain JavaScript, you can access the innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('processorTitle').innerHTML;
```

or change it:

```
document.getElementById('processorTitle').innerHTML = 'your text';
```

To use jQuery to access the value of innerHTML, use `.html()`:

```
$('#processorTitle').html();
```

or change it:

```
$('#processorTitle').html('your text');
```

If you continue to have trouble after making this change, be sure that you included the jQuery library into your page to use the jQuery features:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```